# How to render multiple components same route path with React-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Im creating a Dashboard page, where I always want to show a Sidebar Component if the route path is /dashboard. But I also want /dashboard to render another component aswell.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

- Route path: **/dashboard** should render the `Sidebar.js` + `Overview.js` components.
- Route path: **/dashboard/account** should render `Sidebar.js` + `Account.js` components.
- Route path: **/dashboard/favorites** should render `Sidebar.js` + `Favorites.js` components.
- And so on...

Can someone point me in the right direction how to achieve this? Cant get my head around it...

**See below to get a more feeling of how I want it:**

[image: Root route path /dashboard]

[image]

This is what I tried so far:

````
              <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
              <Route path="/podcast/:podId/:podName" component={Podcast} />
              <Route exact path="/categori/:categoryName" component={Category} />
              <AuthRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
              <AuthRoute path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            </Switch>
            <Route
              path="/dashboard"
              render={({ match: { url } }) => (
                <>
                  <Route path={`${url}/`} component={Sidebar} />
                  <Route path={`${url}/`} component={Overview} />
                  <Route path={`${url}/favorites`} component={Favorites} />
                </>
              )}
            />```
````

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you render the route from the /dashboard path. Then nested inside that, place the Sidebar component, so it will always render it for any dashboard route. For all nested routes, wrap them in a Switch (or Routes if already using v6). For the Overview component which should be on the Dashboard Home, use the same path and mark it as exact. Then place any other routes you need to render underneath.

```
<Route path="/dashboard">

    // should always render sidebar
    <SideBar /> 
    
    // Switch is needed, otherwise it would render all routes that match.
    // Note that Switch is called Routes in v6 of react-router
    <Switch>

        // needs to be exact, so it does not match on more nested routes
        // otherwise it would always match this route
        <Route path="/dashboard" exact>
            <Overview />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/dashboard/account">
            <Account />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/dashboard/favorites">
            <Favorites />
        </Route>

    </Switch>

</Route>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should go for composition. Create page components that bring the components together and add the pages to the router.

for e.g. FavoritePage.js will be

```js
<div>
  <Sidebar />
  <Favorites>
</div>
```

Likewise for the other pages

Then in Router you will have

```js
<Route path={`${url}/`} component={OverviewPage} />
<Route path={`${url}/favorites`} component={FavoritesPage} />
```

Alternatively if you want the sidebar to be static. Refer https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

```js
   <Router>
      <div>
        <Sidebar />
        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/overview">
            <Overview />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/overview">
            <Favorites />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Overview />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.. This re-render the Sidebar component every time.

Comment: Updated answer with an alternative for moving the sidebar out

Comment: The updated answer dosen't solve my problem. With your solution The Sidebar will be rendered on the path: "/". I want it to render on "/dashboard"...